# How to generate a cyclic sequence of numbers without using looping?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to generate a cyclic sequence of numbers like: `[A B C A B C]` with arbitrary length `N` I tried:

```
import numpy as np
def cyclic(N):
    x = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0]) # The main sequence
    y = np.tile(x,N//3) # Repeats the sequence N//3 times 
    return y
```

but the problem with my code is if i enter any integer which ain't dividable by three then the results would have smaller length (`N`) than I excpected. I know this is very newbish question but i really got stuck

Comment: Is this always a 1d array?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar Yes the first answer with higher rate, but why ?

Comment: Because then you can consider accepting answer. For more info - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `numpy.resize`

```
x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])

y = np.resize(x, 13)

y
Out[332]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.])
```

WARNING: This is answer does not extend to 2D, as `resize` flattens the array before repeating it.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1 :** Here'e one approach to handle generic sequences using [`modulus`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to generate those cyclic indices -

```
def cyclic_seq(x, N):
    return np.take(x, np.mod(np.arange(N),len(x)))
```

**Approach #2 :** For performance, here's another method that tiles to the multiple of the max number of intervals and then making use of [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to select the first `N` elements -

```
def cyclic_seq_v2(x, N):   
    return np.tile(x,(N+N-1)//len(x))[:N]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [81]: cyclic_seq([6,9,2,1,7],14)
Out[81]: array([6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 6, 9, 2, 1])

In [82]: cyclic_seq_v2([6,9,2,1,7],14)
Out[82]: array([6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 6, 9, 2, 1, 7, 6, 9, 2, 1])
```

---

**Runtime test**

```
In [327]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(3))

In [328]: %timeit np.resize(x, 10000) # @Daniel Forsman's solution
     ...: %timeit list(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(x),10000)) # @Chris soln
     ...: %timeit cyclic_seq(x,10000) # Approach #1 from this post
     ...: %timeit cyclic_seq_v2(x,10000) # Approach #2 from this post
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 296 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 185 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 120 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.7 µs per loop

In [329]: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(30))

In [330]: %timeit np.resize(x, 10000) # @Daniel Forsman's solution
     ...: %timeit list(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(x),10000)) # @Chris soln
     ...: %timeit cyclic_seq(x,10000) # Approach #1 from this post
     ...: %timeit cyclic_seq_v2(x,10000) # Approach #2 from this post
     ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 115 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.2 µs per loop

In [331]: %timeit np.resize(x, 100000) # @Daniel Forsman's solution
     ...: %timeit list(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(x),100000)) # @Chris soln
     ...: %timeit cyclic_seq(x,100000) # Approach #1 from this post
     ...: %timeit cyclic_seq_v2(x,100000) # Approach #2 from this post
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 297 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 942 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 ms per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 88.3 µs per loop
```

On performance, `approach #2` seems to be working quite well.

Comment: I think you want `return np.tile(x,(N//len(x))+1)[:N]`, right now, for example, `cyclic_seq_v2([6,9,2,1,7],7)` returns `array([6, 9, 2, 1, 7])`

Comment: It's also pretty disappointing that despite this being the only possible use anyone could have for `np.resize`, there's a one-liner that is at least 5x faster.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using `numpy` over `itertools` for this task?

Comment: @Chris_Rands That's doing not as bad as I thought! In fact its beating `numpy.resize` on one of three scenarios I presented in my timings test. Nice!

Comment: Thanks! I guess the advantage of `itertools` is when you want an iterator rather than list or numpy array. Anyway, +1 for all those benchmarks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.cycle`, an infinite iterator, for this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> it = itertools.cycle([1,2,3])
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
2
>>> next(it)
3
>>> next(it)
1
```

You get a specific length of sequence (`N`), combine it with `itertools.islice`:

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle([1,2,3]),11))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

EDIT: as you can see in [Divakar's benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318156/6260170), this approach is generally intermediate in terms of speed compared to other answers. I recommend when this solution when you want an iterator `return`ed rather than a `list` or `numpy` array.

Answer (score 0):

First over-length it (using `math.ceil`) then `resize` it after `tile`

```
import numpy as np
import math
def cyclic(N):
    x = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0]) # The main sequence
    y = np.tile(x, math.ceil(N / 3.0))
    y = np.resize(y, N)
    return y
```

After taking [Daniel Forsman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4427777/daniel-forsman)'s suggestion, it can be simplified as

```
import numpy as np
def cyclic(N):
    x = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0]) # The main sequence
    y = np.resize(x, N)
    return y
```

because `np.resize` automatically tiles the response in 1D

Comment: `np.resize` automatically tiles the response in 1D, so there's no need for an extra step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools cycle for that.

```
In [3]: from itertools import cycle
In [4]: for x in cycle(['A','B','C']):
...:     print(x)
...:
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
C
A
B
```

**Edit:**
If you want to implement it with out loops, you are going to need recursive functions. Solutions based on itertools cycle and the like are just hiding the loops behind the imported function.

```
In [5]: def repeater(arr, n):
   ...:     yield arr[0]
   ...:     yield arr[1]
   ...:     yield arr[2]
   ...:     if n == 0:
   ...:         yield StopIteration
   ...:     else:
   ...:          yield from repeater(arr, n-1)
   ...:
```

Comment: Combine `cycle` with `islice` to easily create a sequence of length n, as I suggested in my answer

Comment: @MrzFarjamirad What is the reasoning for avoiding `if` statements, when they are simply hidden behind an import.

Comment: @Chris_Rands itertools.cycle is implemented using loops and as the OP pointed out in his comment he doesnt want to use any loops.

Comment: @greole Thanks for your answer. But i think the whole point of working with arrays in python is, avoiding ordinary controle structures like **if** and replace 'em with something much more efficient.Thats all.